# What is the easyiest way to create a tabbed menu?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

What is the easiest way in rails to create a tabbed menu?

I was thinking about creating some if statements example:

```
<li class="<% if current.page = root_url %>currentpage<% end %>">Frontpage</li>
<ul id="submenu">
  <li><b style="text-decoration:underline">Forside 1</b></li>
  <li>Forside 45 </li>
</ul>
```

Here is my HTML for my menu:

```
<li>Frontpage</li>
<ul id="submenu">
  <li><b style="text-decoration:underline">Forside 1</b></li>
  <li>Forside 45 </li>
</ul>

<li>Frontpage 2</li>
<ul id="submenu">
  <li><b style="text-decoration:underline">Forside 1</b></li>
  <li>Forside 3 </li>
</ul>

<li>Frontpage 3</li>
<ul id="submenu">
  <li><b style="text-decoration:underline">Forside 1</b></li>
  <li>Forside 3 </li>
</ul>
```

I just want to style the current li element for the page. Example if a user is on Frontpage 2 the class currentpage is added to the li element for Frontpage 2 or if the user visit a subpage of Frontpage 2 it still have the class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way would be using one gem instead of building it all from the ground up.

Take a look at [this section of the ruby toolbox](https://www.ruby-toolbox.com/categories/rails_menu_builders.html).

If your question is "how do I apply style to the menu", I suggest you create a different question, and tag it "CSS". You will probably get a lot of good answers. I particularly like how the [twitter bootstrap css lib does its navigation/tabs](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/#navigation).